# Run the script in context of the bundle (bundle exec) is disabled in Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubymine, rubymine-7

for all rspec its not possible to enable to run rspec in context of bundle (bundle exec). Why?

[image]

Comment: Try uninstalling all your Ruby installations except one, then get sure that the 'bundler' gem is installed for that Ruby installation and try again.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is because (by default) Rubymine is using the @global gemset in your Ruby SDK settings for your project (and the bundler gem is not installed in your @global gemset). I could be wrong.

If you use bundler and rvm (or rbenv I suspect), you can enable bundler by unchecking the "global" checkbox in your settings panel.

[image: My Rubymine 2017.1 Settings]

Answer (score 0):

It is enabled for me. Whenever weird stuff like this happens for me, I close all instances of RubyMine and delete the .idea directory from the project root. It will be recreated the next time you open the project. This .idea file corruption infrequently happens to me when I switch major project details, like Ruby versions.

Answer (score 0):

Edit `.idea/workspace.xml` and replace find:  `<EXTENSION ID="BundlerRunConfigurationExtension" bundleExecEnabled="false" />` and switch `bundleExecEnabled` to true

Remember about closing the project before you start editing the XML.